# Java - Object-Pool with same references

Tags: java, reference, equals, pool

As a simple personal exercise I want to do the following:

- Create a class, which represent a single integer value
- No two objects of this class with the same integer value should exist at any moment in time

This is how I approach the problem:

```
public class MyClass {

   // Static pool
   private static HashSet<MyClass> pool;

   // Integer value each object holds
   private int value;

   static {
     pool = new HashSet<MyClass>();
   }

   // private Constructor
   private MyClass(int value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   // Static public method to create MyClass objects
   public MyClass create(int value) {
      // Create tmp object with private constructor
      MyClass tmp = new MyClass(value);

      // At this point I want to check, whether an object with the
      // same integer value exists in the HashSet.
      // If this is the case I would like to return a reference to
      // the object in the HashSet (the GC will remove tmp).
      // Otherwise I would like to add tmp to the HashSet and return
      // a reference to tmp.
   }

}
```

Part of the question is written as part of a comment in the code posted above. I'm curious about the following things. If I don't overwrite `equals(Object obj)`, `pool.contains(tmp)` will always return false (since the default `equals(Object obj)` inherited from `Object` tests for reference. I could overwrite `equals(Object obj)` to compare the `value`-fields of the objects, but how would I get the reference out of the HashSet to return it?

Do I need to do anything with `hashcode()`?

Comment: Any reason not to use a `Map<Integer, MyClass>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8, use a `Map<Integer, MyClass>`:

```
private static Map<Integer, MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, in your method:

```
public MyClass create(int value) {
  synchronized (map) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(value, MyClass::new);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `computeIfAbsent(value, MyClass::new)`.

Comment: Could you please a little bit, what this magic lines do? `synchronized`, `computeIfAbsent` + *LambdaMagic*...

Comment: [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) is described in the method's Javadoc. `synchronized` is necessary because it's a HashMap, and ["If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). The lambda is simply a thing to create the new instance if the key isn't currently in the map.

Comment: Okay, and I can just pass the `value` as first argument, even though it is not of Object type `Integer`?

Comment: It's called [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: By the way would I get problems if I create a new `Integer`-object? How is checked, whether the key exists? Is the comparison done via reference or the value of the `Integer`-Object?

Comment: The value. This is why it's important to implement equals and hashCode for types you use as keys in hash-based data structures. [See the documentation of `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `Map<Integer, MyClass>`.

Comment: I can accept the answer in 6  minutes. I'm excited for the answer below as well though.

Comment: @Matthias - do make sure you understand that one.. I didn't want to complicate things but since it's out there...